# Convert F# failwith to Scala

Tags: scala, exception, f#

How is it possible to convert a F# failwith exception to Scala.
I have the following code:

```
 let rec getAny text = 
    let FailureText = "Text."
    if test then failwith FailureText
    else text
```

Just throw an Exception like the following?

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Text.");
```

In F# it would throw an Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FailureException. 
What would you throw in Scala? Just a normal java.lang.Exception or RuntimeException?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `sys.error(failureText)`, it just throws a `RuntimeException`. Otherwise, throw is fine if you want to choose another exception, or if error does not convey the intent.

You may also consider `assert`, `assume` or `require` (defined in Predef)

And of course you may dispense with the `else`, but this is a matter of taste.